# Putting aggregations in group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having trouble displaying the data how I would like.  I would like to make 2 rows, with  1 column each displaying like:

```
Home Wins | Visitor Wins
------------------------
  3       |      2
```

I assume my issue is adding the Case When to the group by, because as of now (without the group by clause) it displays:

```
Home Wins | Visitor Wins
------------------------
  1       |      1
```

.

```
SELECT
  sum(CASE WHEN ga_home_score > ga_visitor_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) "Home Wins",
  sum(CASE WHEN ga_home_score < ga_visitor_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) "Visitor Win"
FROM dl_game g
  JOIN dl_team ht ON g.ga_home_id = ht.te_id
  JOIN dl_team vt ON g.ga_home_id = vt.te_id
WHERE ga_schedule_date <= '15-JUN-12'
GROUP BY ((CASE WHEN ga_home_score > ga_visitor_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
          (CASE WHEN ga_home_score < ga_visitor_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END));
```

Comment: who know what your trouble is, as you don't show any of the input data.

Comment: You might want to get familiar with SQLFiddle.com. You can build your test tables and run queries against them, and by supplying a link to the page showing your tables and query you can make it easier for people to help you. Just a suggestion. (And @OldProgrammer is right - having data available to reproduce the issue is important). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT  (CASE WHEN ga_home_score > ga_visitor_score THEN 'Home Wins'
              WHEN ga_home_score > ga_visitor_score THEN 'Visitor Win'
              ELSE 'Tie'
          END), COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM dl_game g JOIN
     dl_team ht
     ON g.ga_home_id = ht.te_id JOIN
     dl_team vt
     ON g.ga_home_id = vt.te_id
WHERE ga_schedule_date <= '15-JUN-12'
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN ga_home_score > ga_visitor_score THEN 'Home Wins'
               WHEN ga_home_score > ga_visitor_score THEN 'Visitor Win'
               ELSE 'Tie'
          END);
```

As your query is written, you probably don't need the `join`s.  All the information is in the games table.